# delegate help code not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Really simple question i think.

i have a main view and a popover view.

i am trying to make a custom delegate which will enable me to close the popover view at certain times. My code is posted below. The real simple issue i am having is my code dosnt appear to be entering the delegate code. Any ideas as to why? It builds and runs but nothing appears to happen, i have put NSLog statments, the popover nslog appears but the function in 
mainview dismissPopover does nothing.

Mainview.h

```
@interface MainScreen : UIViewController<DismissPopoverDelegate>
```

Mainview.m

```
- (void) dismissPopover:(NSNumber *)dataa
{ /* Dismiss you popover here and process data */
[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"OLOLO");    
}
```

Popover.h

```
@protocol DismissPopoverDelegate
- (void) dismissPopover:(NSNumber *)yourDataToTransfer;
@end


@interface SelectAgePopOver : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>{

NSArray *items;
id<DismissPopoverDelegate> delegate;


}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DismissPopoverDelegate> delegate;
```

Popover.m

```
[self.delegate dismissPopover:selrow];
```

where i want the delegate called.

Thanks

the popover view is called by the following method in main view.m

```
       controller = [[SelectAgePopOver alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectAgePopOver" bundle:nil];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    [popoverController setDelegate:self];


    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 294);

   if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        CGRect popRect = CGRectMake((self.AgeRangeTextField.frame.origin.x+50),
                                    (self.AgeRangeTextField.frame.origin.y+50),
                                    (self.AgeRangeTextField.frame.size.width),
                                    (self.AgeRangeTextField.frame.size.height));
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the SelectAgePopOver instance to the MainScreen (self) in the Mainview.m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On where you instantiate the instance of the SelectAgePopOver, you need to set the delegate of the SelectAgePopOver instance to the MainScreen (self) in the Mainview.m, for example:

```
controller = [[SelectAgePopOver alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectAgePopOver" bundle:nil];
;
controller.delegate = self;
```

Please try to set the controller delegate as shown above.

In the SelectAgePopOver.h class file, you do not need to set `UIPopOverControllerDelegate` though.

Comment: @ verbumdei, this is not really an answer and it is more suitable as a comment. I am not down voting it but next time place this type question in a comment area and then offer an answer with more details related. Just FYI

Comment: @CodeMonkey: thanks for the info. I have edited this. Next time I will ask question in the comment :)

Comment: @user2336727: I have edited this answer with an example, but you need to adjust it to how you allocate the instance.

Comment: @user2336727: you also need to set the delegate of `controller`, the same `controller` passed as param in `initWithContentViewController:controller`.

Comment: i have edited the code above to show how i call the popover view